# 404 when wp_enqueue_script my JS file

Tags: wordpress

i try to load my custom JS file named wpm-script.js with :

```
function add_js_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-wpm', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/script-wpm.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );

    wp_localize_script('script-wpm', 'ajaxurl', admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_js_scripts');
```

My script-wpm.js file is like :

```
$('document').ready(function() {

$('body').on('change', '#s', function() {
    var keyword = $(this).val();

    jQuery.post(
        ajaxurl,
        {
            'action': 'search',
            'keyword': keyword
        },
        function(response){
            $('.somewhere').html(response);
        }
    );
});

});
```

And i have a 404 in the console :

[image: screenshot]

Somebody knows how to fix this please?

Comment: Are you currently working in a child theme?

Comment: Yes i use a child theme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the following:

`get_template_directory_uri()`

Replace it with:

`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` as it refers to the current theme folder.

Comment: Yes, if OP is using a child theme, then you're correct.

Comment: it's recommend to use get_template_directory_uri() in parent theme - So in short use get_template_directory_uri when you are creating a parent theme and get_stylesheet_directory_uri when creating a child theme.

Comment: I have a blank page when i change my get_template_directory_uri() with get_styleshsheet_directory_uri().

Do you know why?

Comment: If you creating a **Child** theme and wanted to access the **Parent** theme folder and its assets then using `get_template_directory_uri` is the one to use. However if the assets are located in the **Current** theme then `get_styleshsheet_directory_uri` is used instead.

Comment: @WebMate sorry for the typo on my code; fixed it though with `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`

Comment: Genius. It was this; Thank you very much